# Dynamically updating listview with notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom `JSONAdapter` class that I want to update on `AsyncTask` `onPostExecute`. However, despite the fact that I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and despite the fact that `getCount()` changes, `getView` is never called.

```
private class JSONAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private final Activity activity;
    private JSONAdapter(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override public int getCount() {
        if (result == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return result.length();
        }
    }

    @Override public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
        return result.optJSONObject(position);
    }

    @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = getItem(position);
        return jsonObject.optLong("id");
    }

    @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        try {
            textView1.setText(result.getJSONObject(position).getString("image"));
            textView2.setText(result.getJSONObject(position).getString("distance"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out why notifyDataSetChanged() wasn't working, but I managed to get around the problem by just recreating and resetting the adapter each time.